# implementing site wide progress indicators

Tags: node.js, angularjs, express, progress-bar

I have a website running on the MEAN Stack (mongo, express, angular, node) and I am using jade as the templating engine for serving partial files. 
Now, I already tried  [ngProgres](http://victorbjelkholm.github.io/ngProgress/#demo) but according to the API it can be used along with the $http services or file uploads only as only there my javascript function is waiting for response and during that time I can use ngProgress but how do i show progress indicator while the partial template files are being retrieved?

Comment: The ngProgres link is broken ..

Comment: victorbjelkholm.github.io/ngProgress/#demo, here is the link again sorry for the broken one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would like all the loading mechanism to happen automatically, have a look at this project:

[Angular Loading Bar](http://chieffancypants.github.io/angular-loading-bar/)

```
An automatic loading bar using angular interceptors. It works automatically,
so simply include it as a dependency and it will automatically display
the progress of your $http requests.
```

For non-angular apps, see: [PACE](http://github.hubspot.com/pace/)

```
an Automatic page load progress bar
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks PACE was what I was looking for, as I already Angular Loading Bar served only $http requests

Comment: But the Angular Loading Bar should work for the partial template files  (do you mean `templateUrl:` or `ng-include`?), since those template are retrieved by `$http` internally.

Comment: Oh, I did not know that thanks for this info and yeah I meant templateUrl and ng-includes both